# How do I password protect a CartoDB Visualization

Tags: carto

We have some data and a visualization that we would like to make available to a small user community.

How do I password protect a CartoDB visualization without making it public.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. It helps us to provide better answers if you can provide some detail in your question. For example, how are you planning to share this visualization? What have you already looked at (e.g. reverse proxy server, web server authentication)? What integration do you need (LDAP/AD, some single-sign-on)? I'm sure these are obvious to you, but we have no understanding of your specific circumstances, so you need to be explicit.

Comment: Are you using a Private or Public account

Comment: I'll answer this question in a week or so hopefully. I have a draft mechanism, but I don't recommend using it until we evaluate and tweak it. We'll also create better documentation for it but it will probably always be for advanced users. https://github.com/andrewxhill/cartodb-examples/blob/gh-pages/security-definer/read-only/README.md I don't recommend messing around with it unless you have a good amount of postgresql under your belt

Answer (score 6):

This functionality is already available in the authoring tool. You need to be a subscriber of the Coronelli plan at least. You have the details in the [pricing page](http://cartodb.com/pricing), and a [blog post explaining the feature](http://blog.cartodb.com/post/78555009263/new-privacy-features-for-visualizations).

Another way of protecting your data is using our APIs and creating a proxy in your app ([here is one done in node.js](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-api-proxy))

Answer (score 1):

I believe password-protection of private tables and visualizations was just brought in recently.  Only catch is that you need a Coronelli or higher plan, which start at $149/month.

Really wish this feature was available on the $50/month plan...

Answer (score 1):

We've included password protected maps. You can see the details on our blog write-up

http://blog.cartodb.com/post/78555009263/new-privacy-features-for-visualizations

For now, it is only available on Coronelli accounts and higher